# Weld cannot find CDI producer method in library jar

Tags: cdi, weld

Using Wildfly 8.2.0.Final, which I believe uses Weld 2.2, I've reproduced this issue with 2 simple classes in a Maven multimodule project. One produces a `javax.ws.rs.client.Client`, another has an injection point for the same. Arquillian deployment fails with `WELD-001408`: unsatisfied dependencies.
The producer is in a library jar that gets included in the `WEB-INF/lib` for the consumer. Producer has a `beans.xml` in the `META-INF` with `discovery-mode=annotation` and the consumer has one in `WEB-INF` with `discovery-mode=all`.

Steps to reproduce:
Download [this project](https://developer.jboss.org/servlet/JiveServlet/download/925111-131502/cdi-producer-consumer.zip) and run `mvn clean install` from the root directory.

This is a critical bug. There're some [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040202/how-to-discover-a-cdi-producer-in-a-war-context) SO posts about Weld unsatisfied dependencies but most of them are because a `beans.xml` was missing. With CDI 1.2, `beans.xml` is optional, though my example does have couple. Any ideas?

Full disclosure: Also posted in Weld forum [255328](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/255328)

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your scenario. I have the consumer getting the injected client properly. Plus, just printed out the injected type to be:
org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClient@6d13d9f7

Comment: @maress The demo project had a mistake that I fixed and it's working now. However, the real project that has this problem is still broken. I'm trying to figure out the differences, if any.

Comment: @maress Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After days of trying to reproduce the issue in another project, but in vain, I reduced the original project to a CDI produce and a consumer and posted the code in JBoss forum and also opened a JIRA [WELD-1921](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-1921). Martin Kouba found out that the problem was caused by using the wrong `Produces` annotation! Instead of `javax.enterprise.inject.Produces`, I had `javax.ws.rs.Produces`. This obviously wasn't intentional and must've happened when I auto-imported the package in Eclipse and somehow picked the wrong one!
There were some other issues too but nothing I couldn't solve myself. Thanks a ton Martin.

Comment: I've had the same thing happen to me.  Definitely easy to do!

Comment: This happens to me all the time…

Comment: Thank you for saving me hours of debugging time! <3