# Annotate variable to be injected by producer

Tags: java, dependency-injection, annotations, cdi

From what I have understood, it should be possible to use a producer to inject any kind of variable in Java with CDI. To test this I created a small unit test.

```
@RunWith(CdiRunner.class)
public class Test {

    @Inject
    @AnIntProducer
    int i; // Variable to be injected

    @org.junit.Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

I then proceed to create the annotation and producer:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD, TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface AnIntProducer {
}

public class TestProducer {

    @Produces
    @AnIntProducer
    public int i() {
        return 503;
    }
}
```

When I run the test I assume that it should print 503, but instead I get:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException:
WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type int with qualifiers @AnIntProducer
  at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject Test.i
  at Test.i(Test.java:0)
```

Somehow it seems that the CdiRunner can't find the producer, and I really dont know why. Is there a problem with my setup or have I just misunderstood how injection works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CdiRunner examines the imports of your test class and builds a mini-deployment based on referenced classes. When you run the test the producer you've defined isn't included in that mini-deployment.

To include additional classes and packages in your test deployment you'll need to add @AdditionalClasses or @AdditionalPackages to your test class.

Example:

```
@RunWith(CdiRunner.class)
@AdditionalClasses(TestProducer.class)
public class Test {
```

You can also use annotations to declare what should be included in the test deployment's beans.xml, so you can activate alternatives, interceptors and decorators that way.

Comment: This makes so much sense! However, when I added TestProducer using AdditionalClasses it still gives me `Unsatisfied dependencies for type int with qualifiers @AnIntProducer`. I also tried adding AnIntProducer to both Test and TestProducer, but still same error.

Comment: Quick check, have you tried using Integer rather than the raw type?

Comment: Yes, same result. I also tried to create the @Produces method in the test class, and that worked. Therefore I concluded that the problem is that the Test class either doesn't include the TestProducer, or that it includes it but doesn't find the class.

Comment: I finally found the solution, I actually had two problems. The first was the one that you noted: TestProducer needed to be added using AdditionalClasses. The second problem was that I used the wrong @Produces, similar to the problem found here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29840651/1137118. Changing to the correct annotation finally solved it.