# Dependency injection of generic type: producer not recognized

Tags: java, generics, cdi, weld

**Situation:** 
I have an `Entity` interface, some entity implementations, and a `Repository` interface, of which I want to produce injectable instances with **CDI** in the following way:

```
@Inject @Generic
private Repository<Product, Long> repository;
```

During initialization of the **Weld** container (I'm using Weld-SE 2.3.4 Final), I get an **exception that indicates my producer wasn't recognized as matching for the injection point**:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
...
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: 
Unsatisfied dependencies for type Repository<Product, Long> with qualifiers @Generic
at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Generic private idx.contacts.persistence.CDITest.repository
```

**I strongly assume that the cause lies with the generics used** (two generic types of which one (the Entity type) depends on the other (the Entity's ID).
When I change in so that both generic types are independent, all works well (but would not make sense for the Entity and Repository).

The `Entity` interface:

```
public interface Entity<ID> extends Serializable {
    // some methods
}
```

An example for such an entity:

```
public class Product implements Entity<Long> {
    // some methods
}
```

CDI qualifier:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
public @interface Generic { }
```

The `Repository` interface for a given entity type:

```
public interface Repository<E extends Entity<ID>, ID> {
    // some methods
}
```

And the `Repository` producer, which would then create instances, but isn't recognized as an appropriate producer for the injection example at the top of this question:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class RepositoryProducer {

    @Produces
    @Generic
    public <ID, E extends Entity<ID>> Repository<E, ID> create(
            final InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
       // would create a repository instance, but is never called
    }
}
```

Is CDI with generics somehow limited to only trivial cases? Could this even work? The generic types are retained (not erased) in the code, I verified this using reflection. Where's the error?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/rmpestano/cdi-generic-dao/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cdi/genericdao/producer/DaoProducer.java) might help you.

Comment: Or maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29840651/2717751).